# how to get val of a text field using jquery ?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".comments").keyup(function(){
            id = this.id;
            comment = $("#com"+id).val();
            alert(comment); 
        });
    });
</script>
<?php
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('contact');
    $where = "admin_id like '%$client_id%'";
    $this->db->where($where);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();
    foreach ($result as $fet) 
    {
?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="comments" class="comments" id="com<?php echo $fet['id']; ?>" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="save" />
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php 
    }
?>
```

In this code I have multiple text field name comments and I want to alert value of multiple comments text field. Here, when I write something it show me undefine. So, How can I get value of comments field using different id ? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: You don’t need to go via the id. But you need to use `$(this)` instead of `this`. `$(this).val()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your keyup event with this one. this.id gives you `com+id` where `id` you set through php code.

```
$(".comments").keyup(function(){
        id = this.id;
        comment = $(this).val();
        alert(comment); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change, as `this.id;` will return `id`, which would be `com123`, but on top of that, you are adding `com` again, which will become `comcom123`

```
        id = this.id;
        comment = $('#'+id).val();
```

Other alternate solution is suggested by other as use `this` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".comments").keyup(function(){
            id = $(this).attr('id');
            comment = $("#"+id).val();
            alert(comment); 
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="comments" class="comments" id="com1" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="save" />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try `this` keyword, No need to go with `id`:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".comments").keyup(function(){
            alert($(this).val()); 
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="comments" class="comments" id="com1" value="this is comment 1" />
<input type="text" name="comments" class="comments" id="com2" value="this is comment 2" />
<input type="text" name="comments" class="comments" id="com3" value="this is comment 3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

So If i understood you correctly, you want to alert each time the user types anything with the value of that specific textbox? Using jQuery, something like this should do it:

```js
$("input[name=textbox1]").on("keyup", function() {
 window.alert($(this).val());
});

$("textarea[name=textbox2]").on("keyup", function() {
 window.alert($(this).val());
});
```

```css
.form-input {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST">
 <label>Textbox Example: </label><input type="text" name="textbox1" placeholder="Type Something.." class="form-input" /> <br /> <br />
 <label>Textarea Example:</label> <textarea name="textbox2" placeholder="Type Something.." class="form-input"> </textarea> <br /> <br />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="form-input" />
</form>
```